# How to migrate firewall rules from CentOS 6 to CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, firewall

Is an

```
iptables-save > save.txt
```

on the CentOS 6 side, and on the CentOS 7 side:

```
iptables-restore < save.txt
```

enough?

Or, because of `firewalld` (which is not in CentOS 6), there are other steps needed?

Comment: That will work if you just wish to use the iptables service on CentOS 7 instead of firewalld.

Comment: Should we turn of firewalld service than?

Comment: Yes, you should if you are just using iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Export Iptables Rules

The iptables-save command writes the current iptables rules to stdout (standard out). This gives us an easy way to export the firewall rules to file, by redirecting stdout to a file.

On the Server A, the one with the iptables rules that you want to migrate, use the iptables-save to export the current rules to a file named "iptables-export" like this:

```
sudo iptables-save > iptables-export
```

This will create the iptables-export file, in your home directory. This file can be used on a different server to load the firewall rules into iptables.

View File Contents (Optional)

Let's take a quick look at the file's contents. We'll use the cat command to print it out to the terminal:

```
cat iptables-export
```

Copy Exported Rules to Destination Server

We need to copy the rules file to our destination server, Server B. The easiest way to do this is to use scp or to copy and paste the file contents to a new file on Server B. We will demonstrate how to use scp to copy the file over the network to the /tmp directory.

On Server A, run this scp command. Be sure to substitute the highlighted parts with your server's login and IP address:

```
scp iptables-export user@new_server:/tmp # /tmp is a example
```

Once you are ready to load the rules from the iptables-export file into iptables, let's use the iptables-restore command to do so.

On Server B, the destination server, run this command to load the firewall rules:

```
sudo iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables-export
```

This will load the rules into iptables. You can verify this with the sudo iptables -S command.